# Much Slower Build Times with SpringBoot 1.4.3

Tags: spring-boot

Anyone else seeing build performance issues with Spring Boot 1.4.3?  Our previous builds with SpringBoot 1.4.2 were taking about 48 seconds with the following gradle command:

```
gradlew clean build
```

After only migrating to Spring Boot 1.4.3 (and therefore pulling in all the associated libraries), they're taking about 3 minutes and 47 seconds.

Comment: And what part of the build exactly takes now more time?

Comment: When doing a clean build, the :processResources, :war, and :bootRepackage are taking 30, 73, and 70 seconds respectively.  With 1.4.2 they complete easily in less than a second.